# Catching user input from popup with validation?

Tags: validation, abap, dynpro, sap-erp

I am trying to put in a variable a value that the user has to introduce from a popup.

I have seen the function `POPUP_GET_VALUES` can be the adiente, but in the parameters that the function requires I see that there is a table to put the value into a field. As it is a unique value, I would like to put it within a single variable previously defined, in order to also be able to establish limits for the user to enter the value, since it has to be a percentage.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use FM `POPUP_TO_GET_ONE_VALUE` and specify texts you want. But you should then check the format of input. For `POPUP_GET_VALUES` you need a table and field to reference, it will check the format for you.

Comment: Thanks! That FM is exactly what i was looking for